Random height in face mode
In edit mode I have number of faces which I want to elevate randomly. How can I do it without selecting every face and draging to change the height ?
For vertices there's randomize vertices. Is there something for faces and heights in edit mode?


why don't you use randomize transform z-scale in object mode? ok, you have to move your pivot points first to z=0 but in your simple case that would be the easiest thing to do

I'm modeling in edit mode. I would have to separate geometry in that case. Where is randomize transform z-scale in object mode ?

search for randomize transform (F3)

I've now tried to separate faces to another geometry but I can't use randomize transform in object mode because they're just plains with zero height.

then just first extrude the faces to cubes ;)

Apart from the solution which @Chris suggested - which requires you separate the columns into individual objects, I'm not sure if this was apparent to you - here is a workaround which is not great but you can use it in simple cases like this (where you want to transform randomly on a single axis).

First of all set the Transform Pivot Point to Individual Origins and enable Proportional Editing with the Falloff set to Random.


Now select the top faces of your columns and press Shift+H to hide everything else except the top faces.


Select a single face (maybe the middle one) and press G Z to move it on the Z axis. Scroll your mouse wheel to make the influence range of the proportional editing very large so it covers all other faces (and much more to make sure you have no influence decrease towards the sides). Now all vertices are moved randomly up and down.


Left-click to confirm the randomization, then press A to select everything. Now with the pivot point set to individual origins scale them all flat on the Z axis by pressing S Z 0.


After this is done, press Alt+H to unhide the rest of the faces.



